# Kendo UI Grid Display Blank Columns

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i am having an issue with the **Telerik Kendo UI grid**. When displaying data on it, some blank spaces show up between the columns.

I will have to be very cheap on displaying the bug here, but i think you'll kind of undertand. [Example of blank columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6uYt.png) the info in the grid its kind of confidential so i cannot show it to you guys, sorry. So instead i will share this image for a little context and explanation.

So, i want to drop those extrange blank columns since they don't actually exists in my model or database. Even without any sort of complete explanation of my problem i have faith that you guys can at least point me into the right direction here, or give me any clue at least, and that's actually all i want and i will be very grateful. Thanks for helping me and have a nice day.

Christian.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all, we cannot read your mind. You might want to create a small workable code, and show us at either [Telerik Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/) or [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/).

Comment: Yes, show your code, but essentially you can provide a list of the columns you want displayed: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns